# how to add addtional buttons by using sitecore webform for marketer

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

When i create a new form in sitecore by using the sitecore webform for marketer module.the form already have a default submit button , but i want to add another button like clear form function.

How could i add a new button in the form design backend?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a built-in way to add a clear button, but you should refer to the [WFFM User Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/web%20forms%20for%20marketers%20v2_3%20user%20guide-usletter.pdf) (**PDF link**) on the SDN on how to use the Form Builder GUI to add fields and buttons/actions.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a built-in way to add a clear button,but you may customize via jquery:

1.add a sublayout(ascx) page  ,then do following

```
   <div class="myDiv sub">
                            <sc:Placeholder ID="phForm" runat="server" Key="Form" />
                            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfCancelButtonText" ClientIDMode="Static" /> 
                            <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Then do following in jquery

```
//adding reset-button in web-forms
if ($('.scfForm .scfSubmitButtonBorder').length > 0) {
    $('.myDiv .scfForm .scfSubmitButtonBorder').prepend('<input type="Reset" class="reset-button" />');
}

//adding reset-button text in My-Account web-form
var $hfCancelButtonText = $('.myDiv').find('#hfCancelButtonText').val();
$('.my-account-detail').find('.reset-button').val($hfCancelButtonText);
```